# Add Service Reference support on VS Code / Mac OSX

Tags: c#, macos, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

We're planning to start our next project on VS Code on MacOSX (targeting .Net Core 1.0) but we have bunch of web services that needs to be consumed in that project.

There is a plug-in for VS 2015 (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c3b3666e-a928-4136-9346-22e30c949c08) but still not sure if we have an option for VS Code MacOSX.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is *currently* no cross-platform version of svcutil to generate WCF proxy classes. You can watch this issue for further updates: https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/1222